# nodejs mysql (libmysqlclient)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I use https://github.com/calzoneman/sync project and get this error. I'm new to nodejs. How to fix this? 
I done all in installation manual

```
root@srv:/var/www/synch# node server.js
Starting CyTube v1.9.5

/var/www/synch/node_modules/mysql-libmysqlclient/lib/mysql-libmysqlclient.js:208
MysqlConnectionQueued.prototype = new bindings.MysqlConnection();
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MysqlConnection' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/synch/node_modules/mysql-libmysqlclient/lib/mysql-libmysqlclient.js:208:47)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/synch/auth.js:12:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Comment: Well, the error says it all : bindings is null. Posting the code from `mysql-libmysqlclient.js` might be more helpful

Comment: @verybadalloc that's part of the [`mysql-libmysqlclient`](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient/blob/master/lib/mysql-libmysqlclient.js) module

Comment: Can you try to add some console.log statements in [mysql-libmysqlclient](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient/blob/master/lib/mysql-libmysqlclient.js), especially in the try-catch block between lines 11 and 33?